# Getting Gradle 'rootProject' object to honor env vars

Tags: gradle, environment-variables

I ran across the following configuration in a Gradle project's buildfile (`build.gradle`):

```
codenarcMain {
    configFile = rootProject.file("gradle/codenarc/CodeNarcMain.groovy")
}
```

When I Google "*Gradle rootProject*" I find [this link](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.initialization.Settings.html#org.gradle.api.initialization.Settings:rootProject) which makes it look like `rootProject` is a `ProjectDescriptor` instance.

But looking at [`ProjectDescriptor`](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/initialization/ProjectDescriptor.html), I don't see any property called `file`. I see a `buildFile` and `projectDir`, but no `file` property.

Ultimately, I am trying to get Gradle to load the CodeNarc config file from *outside* the build directory. On my system I have an env var called `$CODENARC_HOME` with the following directory structure:

```
CODENARC_HOME/ (say this is /home/myuser/tools/codenarc/)
    CodeNarcMain.groovy
    CodeNarcTest.groovy
    README.md
```

Now I would like to change the CodeNarc config in Gradle to look something like this:

```
codenarcMain {
    configFile = rootProject.file("CODENARC_HOME/CodeNarcMain.groovy")
}
```

And then, no matter where `CODENARC_HOME` is defined, the Gradle build will still be able to locate the config file.

So my questions:

1. What is the `file` property on `rootProject`, and why don't I see it in the API docs (linked above)?; and
2. How to get `rootProject.file(...)` to honor system/env vars inside its file path string argument?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`rootProject` in `settings.gradle` is-a `ProjectDescriptor`. `rootProject` in `build.gradle` is-a `Project`. Environment variables and system properties can be accessed in the standard Java way:

```
codenarcMain {
    configFile = rootProject.file("${System.getenv("CODENARC_HOME")}/CodeNarcMain.groovy")
    // or: System.getProperty("codenarc.home")
}
```

Comment: Thanks (again) @Peter Niederwieser (+1)